# Angular ng-bind or interpolation when used inside other attributes?

Tags: angularjs, interpolation, ng-bind

I'm quite new to Angular 1.5+ and I was trying to understand why should I use ng-bind instead of interpolation. It seems that it's much more efficient, and it will prevent the unrendered {{ }}.

But what should I use, if I'm using it inside other html attributes or other angular directives ? Is it good practice to mix both ?

```
<h1>Hello <span ng-bind="$ctrl.child"></span></h1>
<img src="resources/images/countries/{{$ctrl.addressCtry}}.png"
     alt="{{$ctrl.addressCtry}}">
```

Comment: How exactly would you use `ngBind` within an attribute value?

Comment: That was my question. Is it possible to use `ngBind` inside other attributes ? If not, is it allowed (or good practice) to mix interpolations (only when needed) and `ngBind`s ?

Comment: Try it in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/1XbXjmepsYDmzs0lBPQI?p=preview). Maybe you can answer your own question.

Comment: Thank your but how is it helping me answer my question ? You're just using an `ngBind` to display data.